# Convert date to character in particular format In R

Tags: r, date, format, character

I need to map 3-4 different dataframes that have different date formats.
How can we convert date in format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

to character in the format:

```
MMM-YY
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create a date object from the string (skip this if your column is already in the Date format):

```
original_date <- as.Date("2017-07-19", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then format the original date to the new format:

```
format(original_date, "%b-%y")   
# "Jul-17"
```

The `%b` indicates the 3-letter abbreviation of the month and `%y` is the year without the century. You can find more of these codes and their meaning here: http://strftime.org/