# Date format does not work in R

Tags: date, format, character

This is my date column which is on my dateframe:

```
data <- data.frame(year_month = c("2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01", "2015-04-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-06-01"))
class(data$year_month)
[1] "factor"
```

**I tried:**

```
 data$year_month1<-as.Date(as.factor(data$year_month), format="%b %Y")
```

**I want:**

```
" Jan 2015", "Feb 2015", "Mar 2015", "Apr 2015", "May 2015", "Jun 2105"
```

**What happens:**
My column on data$year_month1 comes Empty.

I tried quite a few solutions that I found here but the format does not change at all or it comes empty.

Help, please>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to character in particular format In R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191025/convert-date-to-character-in-particular-format-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format(as.Date(data$year_month), format="%b %Y")

#first convert to Date, without as.factor (why did you do that?)
#then convert it to character as you want it, with format()
```

Comment: Because when I was looking around I saw some solutions where they used as.factor to change it... Stupid, I know. But thank you so much, it fixed my problem.